# How to turn on remote debug on app that run on a docker container?

Tags: java, docker, intellij-idea, java-11

I'm using `Intellij IDEA` and I run my application on docker container and I need to attach remote debug for my application. But if I use `java 8` all works is fine but if I assemble my application using `java 11` I couldn't attach remote debug to my app that is running in the Docker container. I get the following error message: 
[image]

that is my debug configuration:
[image]
What is I'm doing wrong?

Comment: does your container expose the port 5005?

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake. I'm running my application on the docker container with a configuration for remote debug for java 8 instead of java 11.
in that params need to be correct:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005
```

I forgot the `*` symbol in the address.